# How to define a sub query inside SQL statement to be used several times as a table alias?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, left-join

I have an MS Access database for rainfall data of several climate stations.

For each day of each station, I want to calculate the rainfall in the previous day (if recorded), and the sum of the rainfall at the previous 3 and 7 days.

Due to the huge amount of data and the limitations of Access, I made a query that takes station by station; Then I applied an auxillary query to find dates first, For each station, The following SQL statement is applied (and named `RainFallStudy` query):

```
SELECT 
    [173].ID, [173].AirportCode, [173].RFmm, 
    DateSerial([rYear], [rMonth], [rDay]) AS DateSer, 
    [DateSer]-1 AS DM1, 
    [DateSer]-2 AS DM2, 
    [DateSer]-3 AS DM3, 
    [DateSer]-4 AS DM4, 
    [DateSer]-5 AS DM5, 
    [DateSer]-6 AS DM6, 
    [DateSer]-7 AS DM7
FROM 
    [173] 
WHERE 
    ((([173].AirportCode) = 786660));
```

I used DM1, DM2, etc as the date serial of the day-1, day-2, etc.

Then I used another query that uses `RainFallStudy` query with left joints as shown in the figure:

[image: Query outline]

The SQL statement is

```
SELECT 
    RainFallStudy.ID, RainFallStudy.AirportCode, 
    RainFallStudy.RFmm AS RF0, RainFallStudy.DateSer, 
    RainFallStudy.DM1, RainFallStudy_1.RFmm AS RF1, 
    RainFallStudy_2.RFmm AS RF2, RainFallStudy_3.RFmm AS RF3, 
    RainFallStudy_4.RFmm AS RF4, RainFallStudy_5.RFmm AS RF5, 
    RainFallStudy_6.RFmm AS RF6, RainFallStudy_7.RFmm AS RF7, 
    Nz([rf1], 0) + Nz([rf2], 0) + Nz([rf3], 0) + Nz([rf4], 0) + Nz([rf5], 0) + Nz([rf6], 0) + Nz([rf7], 0) AS RF_W
FROM 
    ((((((RainFallStudy 
LEFT JOIN 
    RainFallStudy AS RainFallStudy_1 ON RainFallStudy.DM1 = RainFallStudy_1.DateSer) 
LEFT JOIN 
    RainFallStudy AS RainFallStudy_2 ON RainFallStudy.DM2 = RainFallStudy_2.DateSer) 
LEFT JOIN 
    RainFallStudy AS RainFallStudy_3 ON RainFallStudy.DM3 = RainFallStudy_3.DateSer) 
LEFT JOIN 
    RainFallStudy AS RainFallStudy_4 ON RainFallStudy.DM4 = RainFallStudy_4.DateSer) 
LEFT JOIN 
    RainFallStudy AS RainFallStudy_5 ON RainFallStudy.DM5 = RainFallStudy_5.DateSer) 
LEFT JOIN 
    RainFallStudy AS RainFallStudy_6 ON RainFallStudy.DM6 = RainFallStudy_6.DateSer) 
LEFT JOIN 
    RainFallStudy AS RainFallStudy_7 ON RainFallStudy.DM7 = RainFallStudy_7.RFmm;
```

Now I suffer from the slow performance of this query, as the records of each station range from 1,000 to 750,000 records! Is there any better way to find what I need in a faster SQL statement? The second question, can I make a standalone SQL statement for that (one query without the auxiliary query) as I will use it in python, which requires one SQL statement (as Iof my knowledge).

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

As requested by @Andre, Here are some sample data of table `[173]` in HTML

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>AirportCode</th><th>rYear</th><th>rMonth</th><th>rDay</th><th>RFmm</th></tr><tr><td>11216</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>23</td><td>0.51</td></tr><tr><td>11217</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>24</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11218</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>25</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11219</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>26</td><td>2.03</td></tr><tr><td>11220</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>27</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11221</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>28</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11222</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>29</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11223</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>30</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11224</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>1</td><td>31</td><td>0.25</td></tr><tr><td>11225</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11226</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11227</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4.32</td></tr><tr><td>11228</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>13.21</td></tr><tr><td>11229</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>1.02</td></tr><tr><td>11230</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11231</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>7</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11232</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>8</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11233</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>9</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11234</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>10</td><td>5.08</td></tr><tr><td>11235</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>11</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11236</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>12</td><td>12.95</td></tr><tr><td>11237</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>13</td><td>5.59</td></tr><tr><td>11238</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>14</td><td>0.25</td></tr><tr><td>11239</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>15</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11240</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>16</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11241</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>17</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11242</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>18</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11243</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>19</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11244</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>20</td><td>14.48</td></tr><tr><td>11245</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>21</td><td>9.65</td></tr><tr><td>11246</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>3.05</td></tr><tr><td>11247</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>23</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11248</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>24</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11249</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>25</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11250</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>26</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11251</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>27</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11252</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>28</td><td>7.37</td></tr><tr><td>11253</td><td>409040</td><td>2012</td><td>2</td><td>29</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

And here is sample output (HTML)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>AirportCode</th><th>DateSer</th><th>ThisDay</th><th>Yesterday</th><th>Prev3days</th><th>PrevWeek</th></tr><tr><td>11216</td><td>409040</td><td>23-01-2012</td><td>0.51</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>11217</td><td>409040</td><td>24-01-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0.51</td><td>0.51</td><td>0.51</td></tr><tr><td>11218</td><td>409040</td><td>25-01-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.51</td><td>0.51</td></tr><tr><td>11219</td><td>409040</td><td>26-01-2012</td><td>2.03</td><td>0</td><td>0.51</td><td>0.51</td></tr><tr><td>11220</td><td>409040</td><td>27-01-2012</td><td>0</td><td>2.03</td><td>2.03</td><td>2.54</td></tr><tr><td>11221</td><td>409040</td><td>28-01-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2.03</td><td>2.54</td></tr><tr><td>11222</td><td>409040</td><td>29-01-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2.03</td><td>2.54</td></tr><tr><td>11223</td><td>409040</td><td>30-01-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2.54</td></tr><tr><td>11224</td><td>409040</td><td>31-01-2012</td><td>0.25</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2.03</td></tr><tr><td>11225</td><td>409040</td><td>01-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0.25</td><td>0.25</td><td>2.28</td></tr><tr><td>11226</td><td>409040</td><td>02-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.25</td><td>2.28</td></tr><tr><td>11227</td><td>409040</td><td>03-02-2012</td><td>4.32</td><td>0</td><td>0.25</td><td>0.25</td></tr><tr><td>11228</td><td>409040</td><td>04-02-2012</td><td>13.21</td><td>4.32</td><td>4.32</td><td>4.57</td></tr><tr><td>11229</td><td>409040</td><td>05-02-2012</td><td>1.02</td><td>13.21</td><td>17.53</td><td>17.78</td></tr><tr><td>11230</td><td>409040</td><td>06-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>1.02</td><td>18.55</td><td>18.8</td></tr><tr><td>11231</td><td>409040</td><td>07-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>14.23</td><td>18.8</td></tr><tr><td>11232</td><td>409040</td><td>08-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1.02</td><td>18.55</td></tr><tr><td>11233</td><td>409040</td><td>09-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>18.55</td></tr><tr><td>11234</td><td>409040</td><td>10-02-2012</td><td>5.08</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>18.55</td></tr><tr><td>11235</td><td>409040</td><td>11-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>5.08</td><td>5.08</td><td>19.31</td></tr><tr><td>11236</td><td>409040</td><td>12-02-2012</td><td>12.95</td><td>0</td><td>5.08</td><td>6.1</td></tr><tr><td>11237</td><td>409040</td><td>13-02-2012</td><td>5.59</td><td>12.95</td><td>18.03</td><td>18.03</td></tr><tr><td>11238</td><td>409040</td><td>14-02-2012</td><td>0.25</td><td>5.59</td><td>18.54</td><td>23.62</td></tr><tr><td>11239</td><td>409040</td><td>15-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0.25</td><td>18.79</td><td>23.87</td></tr><tr><td>11240</td><td>409040</td><td>16-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>5.84</td><td>23.87</td></tr><tr><td>11241</td><td>409040</td><td>17-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.25</td><td>23.87</td></tr><tr><td>11242</td><td>409040</td><td>18-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>18.79</td></tr><tr><td>11243</td><td>409040</td><td>19-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>18.79</td></tr><tr><td>11244</td><td>409040</td><td>20-02-2012</td><td>14.48</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>5.84</td></tr><tr><td>11245</td><td>409040</td><td>21-02-2012</td><td>9.65</td><td>14.48</td><td>14.48</td><td>14.73</td></tr><tr><td>11246</td><td>409040</td><td>22-02-2012</td><td>3.05</td><td>9.65</td><td>24.13</td><td>24.13</td></tr><tr><td>11247</td><td>409040</td><td>23-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>3.05</td><td>27.18</td><td>27.18</td></tr><tr><td>11248</td><td>409040</td><td>24-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>12.7</td><td>27.18</td></tr><tr><td>11249</td><td>409040</td><td>25-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3.05</td><td>27.18</td></tr><tr><td>11250</td><td>409040</td><td>26-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>27.18</td></tr><tr><td>11251</td><td>409040</td><td>27-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>27.18</td></tr><tr><td>11252</td><td>409040</td><td>28-02-2012</td><td>7.37</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>12.7</td></tr><tr><td>11253</td><td>409040</td><td>29-02-2012</td><td>0</td><td>7.37</td><td>7.37</td><td>10.42</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Check if you have indexes for all columns used in joins and in WHERE clause. Also I would recommend to redesign the database, don't keep the data for each day in separate column, use one column in new table for this. Also Access has 2 Gb file limitation, if you have big data volumes, consider migration of backend to SQL database like MySQL or MS SQL.

Comment: @SergeyS. Thank you for your suggestions, But I used each day in a separate row (record) not column. Regarding the migration to MySQL or other DB, It may require a good amount of time to master them while I am just a researcher who uses MS-Access to perform research. so if possible to use Access even with python, I would appreciate it.

Comment: This is a very weird query design that is most certainly not necessary. Please post some sample data of your original table (`[173]` ?) and the result you want to get from it. http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: @Andre Thanks for your help, I will update the post with sample data.

Comment: Thanks. Things would be easier if the date would be stored in a single DateTime column. E.g. "Sum all data between DateX-3 and DateX". This can be done with `DateSerial()` as you did in your query, but it will impact performance **a lot** because the function result isn't indexed. Can the table design be changed from rYear/rMonth/rDay to a single DateTime column?

Comment: @Andre The data is stored as received from source, but sure I can add a dateSerial column to the original date to avoid lengthy calculations. But what would be the next step? should the same query applies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an additional column `rDate` (DateTime) and filled it with this query:

```
UPDATE Rainfall SET Rainfall.rDate = DateSerial([rYear],[rMonth],[rDay]);
```

Then your desired result can be achieved with several subqueries, using `SUM()` for the last two columns:

```
SELECT r.ID, r.AirportCode, r.rDate, r.RFmm,
(SELECT RFmm FROM Rainfall r1 WHERE r1.AirportCode = r.AirportCode AND r1.rDate = r.rDate-1) AS Yesterday,
(SELECT SUM(RFmm) FROM Rainfall r3 WHERE r3.AirportCode = r.AirportCode AND r3.rDate BETWEEN r.rDate-3 AND r.rDate-1) AS Prev3days,
(SELECT SUM(RFmm) FROM Rainfall r7 WHERE r7.AirportCode = r.AirportCode AND r7.rDate BETWEEN r.rDate-7 AND r.rDate-1) AS PrevWeek
FROM Rainfall r
```

Make sure `AirportCode` and `rDate` are indexed for larger numbers of records.

Result:

```
+-------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  ID   | AirportCode |   rDate    | RFmm  | Yesterday | Prev3days | PrevWeek |
+-------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 11216 |      409040 | 23.01.2012 |  0,51 |           |           |          |
| 11217 |      409040 | 24.01.2012 |     0 |      0,51 |      0,51 |     0,51 |
| 11218 |      409040 | 25.01.2012 |     0 |         0 |      0,51 |     0,51 |
| 11219 |      409040 | 26.01.2012 |  2,03 |         0 |      0,51 |     0,51 |
| 11220 |      409040 | 27.01.2012 |     0 |      2,03 |      2,03 |     2,54 |
| 11221 |      409040 | 28.01.2012 |     0 |         0 |      2,03 |     2,54 |
| 11222 |      409040 | 29.01.2012 |     0 |         0 |      2,03 |     2,54 |
| 11223 |      409040 | 30.01.2012 |     0 |         0 |         0 |     2,54 |
| 11224 |      409040 | 31.01.2012 |  0,25 |         0 |         0 |     2,03 |
| 11225 |      409040 | 01.02.2012 |     0 |      0,25 |      0,25 |     2,28 |
| 11226 |      409040 | 02.02.2012 |     0 |         0 |      0,25 |     2,28 |
| 11227 |      409040 | 03.02.2012 |  4,32 |         0 |      0,25 |     0,25 |
| 11228 |      409040 | 04.02.2012 | 13,21 |      4,32 |      4,32 |     4,57 |
| 11229 |      409040 | 05.02.2012 |  1,02 |     13,21 |     17,53 |    17,78 |
+-------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Use `Nz()` to avoid NULL values in the first row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, I will apply the method and return back

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Andre. It works fine on reasonably sized databases, but My database file is approaching 2GB, which is beyond the capabilities of MS-Access. To avoid that, I have to split my tables and work on each separately or to migrate to SQL-Server. Deeper thanks, and best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you store the day in separate fields (rYear, rMonth, rDay). So, in order to get the date you use the DateSerial function. This means that in order to use the date for a join or where clause, Access must calculate the date for the entire table. You need to store the date in a separate field and index it to avoid the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The date column can be added, then what will be next?

Comment: Make sure you index it. Then simply make all of your joins on that column.